# browserify.external() not excluding external libraries

Tags: browserify

I have a project using react and browserify, compiled with a gulp script. I have the following line in my gulpfile:

```
bundler.external(['react', 'react-dom']);
```

Yet I still see a bunch of react libraries bundled with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that packages specified in `browserify.external()` do not include their subpackages.

In other words, even though I specified `react-dom`, when I required something like

```
var server = require('react-dom/server');
```

It would include all the code in that package (and seemingly its dependencies) in my bundle.

Changing my gulpfile code to

```
bundler.external(['react', 'react-dom', 'react-dom/server']);
```

Fixed the issue.